# es6のアロー関数は通常の関数と同じ？

Tags: javascript, es6

```
const Message = props => <div>{props.msg}</div>
```

と、

```
function Message(props) {
    return (
        <div>{props.msg}</div>
        )
}
```

は同じですか？

どこかで確かめることはできますか？

Comment: 実行結果は同じものが返るかもしれませんが、`const Message`は変数宣言なので、この宣言前に`Message(props)`を実行するとエラーが発生します。`function Message()`は関数定義なので、この定義より前で実行しても期待通り動作します。

Answer (score 2):

違います。

通常の関数定義によって定義された関数は `new` で呼び出せますが、アロー関数はできません。

```js
var Foo = function(){};
var foo = new Foo();  // OK
```

```js
var Foo = () => {};
var foo = new Foo();  // エラー
```

また、今回の例では出てきませんが、通常の関数とアロー関数では `this` の扱いにも差があります。
より詳しくは、本家 Q&A の ["Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/5989200) や MDN の[「アロー関数」](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions)をご覧ください。

(このような問題は、英語で "〇〇 vs ××" と検索すると上手く出てくるような気がします。また、最終的には仕様を読むのが良いと思います。)